# Same TableAdapter, Different DB

Tags: c#, .net, database, vb.net, tableadapter

having to work in two parallel environments, developement and production, I want to use the same TableAdapter to connect to different databases (two Oracle databases running on different servers) with the very same structure. How is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by different databases. Two SQL server databases running on different (or the same) servers. Or two brands of databases, like Oracle and SQL Server?

Comment: two Oracle databases running on different servers

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing connnectionstring value of your application database connection?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use TableAdapter before, I always delete them when I create my DataSet. Instead I use DataAdapters.

This might help to change TableAdapter's connection string, but I didn't try it :

[Change a database connection string from code](http://codebetter.com/blogs/peter.van.ooijen/archive/2006/08/11/Change-a-database-connection-string-from-code.aspx)